# Thing-Connection in eclipse ditto

Tags: eclipse-ditto, eclipse-iot, eclipse-digital-twin

1. Can a single thing have multiple connection, if so can all of them be active at the same time?
2. I'm exploring the eclipse ditto recently and I wanted to know whether below given approach is correct for finding the connection a 'thing' uses. I'm trying to get the connection a 'thing' uses, by mapping the thing-policy's authorization subject with authorization context of connections.

```
const matchingSourceConnection = connections.filter((connection) => {
    return (
        connection.sources &&
        connection.sources[0].authorizationContext &&
        connection.sources[0].authorizationContext.some((context) => authorizationSubjects.includes(context))
    ); 
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code checks each source in every connection, which can provide a more comprehensive match.

```
const matchingSourceConnection = connections.filter((connection) => {
    return connection.sources &&
        connection.sources.some(source => 
            source.authorizationContext &&
            source.authorizationContext.some((context) => authorizationSubjects.includes(context))
        ); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually needed to know if its the right approach in regards to eclipse ditto for finding a thing's connection.